# GCMParameterSpec or similar for Android API 16 to 18

Tags: android, node.js, encryption, node-crypto

I wanted to create a function to decrypt an encrypted aes-256-gcm message by nodejs

```
async decrypt_pw(password, key) {
    const key = 'secret';
    const pwBuffer = Buffer.from(password, 'hex');
    const authTag = pwBuffer.slice(-16);
    const iv = pwBuffer.slice(0, 12);
    const encryptedMessage = pwBuffer.slice(12, -16);
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv, { authTagLength: 16 });
    decipher.setAuthTag(authTag);
    let messagetext = decipher.update(encryptedMessage);
    messagetext = Buffer.concat([messagetext, decipher.final()]).toString();
    return messagetext;
}
```

Upon referring online solutions, it requires GCMParameterSpec which is API 19 and above.

```
GCMParameterSpec gcmSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(tagSize, new byte[gcm.getBlockSize()]);
```

How can I get access to GCMParameter on API 16 or any alternative for aes-256-gcm decryption?

Comment: Use AES with HmacSHA512? it is available since API 1.

Comment: Sorry to ask but how to set auth tag using AES with HmacSHA512?

Comment: You need to derive two keys from your key by using a KDF like HKDF, then use the second key with HMACSHA612(key2, message). HMAC provides you data integrity and the authenticity of a message like any MAC. GCM is a mode of operation that provides confidentiality, integrity and authentication. The confidentiality comes from the AES.

Comment: I tried to use IvParameterSpec, but it says it only allow length 16. GCM uses length 12.

Comment: I'm saying that don't use AES-GCM if you want to use android.cipher for API 18 to 10. Use AES with HMACSHA512. If you are insisting then use external libraries line BouncyCastle

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at your initialization:

```
const iv = pwBuffer.slice(0, 12);
...
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv, { authTagLength: 16 });
```

and `GCMParameterSpec`'s parameters:

```
GCMParameterSpec(int tLen, byte[] src)
```

Here `tLen` is the tag length in bits, so it is `authTagLength * 8`, it would need to have 128 bit value.

The badly named `src` parameter is for the IV and is therefore identical to your `iv` parameter, which is 12 bytes in the code.

Fortunately, both the 96 bit IV (or rather nonce) and 128 bit authentication tag *are the default values for GCM*. So basically you can just use:

```
new IvParameterSpec(iv)
```

in your Android code. This was standard practice until `GCMParameterSpec` could be used to add the authentication tag size configuration option.

---

For other readers: if the IV is **not** 12 bytes then you first have to check if the GCM implementation supports differently sized IV values.

If the authentication tag is shorter (it should range between 32 bits and 128 bits in 8 bit increments, with 96-128 being relatively secure) then verification is going to fail for Java - there doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve the calculated authentication tag outside the ciphertext. So in that case you have to jump to loops and get a different implementation that doesn't use `Cipher`.

Comment: Sure, it's getting the GCM specific `CipherSpi` implementation of the provider to accept it that's the trick. Of course, with Android, I think you don't have to sign your providers, so copying a GCM implementation and putting it in at higher prio (lower index) of the other GCM implementation would also work. Seems a bit much if your authentication tag is the recommended 16 bytes anyway though.